# How to add a button to a PDF that sends all the data to a REST API?

Tags: pdf, borb

We need to create a PDF dynamically that is fillable.

I would like to add a button to the form that says Submit. When the user clicks on the button, all the form fields should be collected and a JS fetch call should send it to a server.

Is this possible using borb?

Here's an example:

```
layout.add(
    FixedColumnWidthTable(number_of_columns=2, number_of_rows=4)
    .add(
        JavaScriptPushButton(
            text="Submit Data",
            javascript="// GET THE FIELDS AND CALL FETCH USING POST VERB HERE.",
            horizontal_alignment=Alignment.RIGHT,
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: @KJ ive seen in government forms as well. The use case is we have to create the files programmatically. Unless there’s a way to get acrobat to create it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for Javascript the forms submission is built into Acrobat and other (NOT All) PDF readers.

Here is a button that sends whatever the user enters to replace `Hello world!` Note the deliberate Mistake so if I change that to `Hello World! or my name then that is the data transmitted behind my back to Example.com, without me accepting any insecure JS code.
[image]

The reply from the server will come back to my incoming folder.

[image]

**OK this is embarrassing**, apparently I shot them a blank PDF on the left, and got an equally reasonable "Thank you for your submission" on the right. <strike>Back to the manual then!</strike> ***see edit below**. However the point is any suitable text in the file will be sent out simply at the push of a button with the **correct** action, as provided by the text editor.

[image]

The offending section was this text code. It says send the data to a forms handler at remote `https://www.example.com?incoming.php`

```
5 0 obj
<</A<</F<</F(https://www.example.com?incoming.php)/FS/URL>>/Flags 514/S/SubmitForm>>/AP<</N 9 0 R>>/BS<</S/B>>/DA(0 g /Helv 12 Tf)/F 4/Ff 65536/FT/Btn/MK<</BC[0 0 0]/BG[.752941 .752941 .752941]/CA(Submit)>>/P 7 0 R/Rect[91.53846 650.30099 163.53845 670.30099]/Subtype/Widget/T(Button1)/Type/Annot>>
endobj
```

So what you need is a button statement (graphics are supplied by any suitable reader). With a send text action and a website that knows what to do for incoming and outgoing data fields.

- [Edit] Apparently the code was good, it was me using example.com not a "Real Server" Correct transmit of the edited field is here. NOTE: it shows the manually corrected `CAPS W`, before I pressed `Submit`. Oddly the Acrobat DC transmittal is older 1.2 format not newer 1.4?

[image]

So just to confirm the newly assigned "WidGet" object that worked was:

```
% BUTTON ACTION (to send file currently set to a test site!, current parent is 9)
% Button1 is the /Title but can be anything like "E.T.PhoneHome" the major function is /Flags 512
7 0 obj
<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/T (Button1)/FT/Btn/MK<</BC [0 0 0]/BG [0.75 0.75 0.75]/CA (Submit)>>/BS<</S/B>>
/A<</S/SubmitForm/Flags 512/F<</FS/URL/F (https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/12345)>>>>
/P 9 0 R/Rect [92 650 164 670]>>/AP <</N 11 0 R>>/DA (0 g /Helv 12 Tf)/F 4/Ff 65536
endobj
```

Looking at the Borb code, I am not sure that Joris used an AcroForm URL submit "ACTION" but a JavaScript in his response to https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb/issues/42#issuecomment-1046043322

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed response. I’ll try it this week and report back