Fillable PDF download in .net after change in preview
I am working on a web application, developed using ASP.NET. I need a functionality to show a pdf file embedded in the form. The pdf file is actually a form with some editable controls like textbox, checkbox etc. I want the users to fill this pdf form and click on submit button to save this file. When submit button is clicked, the pdf file with the data filled by the user should be saved on the server. I need help with the last step that how to upload the file to the server.
I know that I can allow users to download the files, edit it and then upload it. But I need to show the file embedded on the web page and it should be saved by clicking a button on that same page, instead of first downloading it and then uploading it back.
I was tried things with iframe for embed pdf then download it. Iframe provide functionality of download but i want download it and store in database.

Web based PDF "forms" follow 3 generic groups.

eXtended Forms Architecture (Proprietary Adobe server licensed
interactive XMP.pdf). Favoured by well paid Organisations such as .gov ! These were historically designed to be used in Windows Internet Explorer or desktop Acrobat. Not well suited for cross platform browsers.

Flatter "Open Source" Licensed AcroForm per ISO Standard
1st downloaded to clients hardware for field entry then later be submitted to a online server forms handler by the client pressing an inherent Acroforms upload button. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78212967/10802527 These should NOT include any "scripting" as that may risk inability to function in secured readers.

HTML Templates as "Work In Progress" to be finally saved in server and "posted" as a PDF via "Download" to client with included data.


Currently you are aiming for something between 2 and 3.
Thus If you wish to avoid building a system that waits minutes, hours, days or even months/years before responding to a submitted form, I suggest your code be based on the third option.
For one such method see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-button-that-submits-a-form-and-downloads-a-pdf-simultaneously
